# Can anyone assist with this contract code project of transferring any deposited eth in my contract to another contract?

Tags: web3js, cryptography

```
const TX = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

let Web3 = require('web3')
let url ='HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545'


let web3 = new  Web3(url)

const contract_account1 ='0x68B010FEd863Cdb12F6bA28e0C19d08773CeCEF2'
const privatekey = Buffer.from('232637df74dbf18a029851f375e6c6888a5a4382411b8ffe4ecb809c84e0e77d','hex',)
const receive_account2 = '0xf74f4dB0F0E05aF8409454867cE8059aBdd3CF8d'
const contract_abi = ''
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(contract_abi, contract_account1)


web3.eth.getTransactionCount(account1, (error,txCount)=>{
  // build a transation object

  const txObject  ={
    nonce:web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
    to: receive_account2,
    value: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')),
    data:contract.method.transfer(receive_account2, web3.utils.toWei('2', 'ether')),
    gasLimit:web3.utils.toHex(21000),
    gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(web3.utils.toWei('10', 'gwei')),
  }
  console.log(txObject)

  //sign transaction with private key of sender

  const tx = new TX(txObject)
  tx.sign(privatekey)

  //serialize the transaction

const serializedTransaction = tx.serialize()
const raw = '0x' + serializedTransaction.toString('hex')

  //broadcast transaction to the network

  web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(raw, (error,txHash) =>{
    console.log(txHash)
  })
})
```

Comment: Please state what the problem is

Comment: I need to create a smart contract functions that automatically transfer eth from my mining address to my personal address